# vite env variable returns undefined in production with vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, vercel

Vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

and this is .env file:

```
VITE_API_KEY = "someKey"
VITE_API_BASE_URL = "baseurl"
```

I use the variables in my project like this:

```
const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL;
const key = import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY;
console.log(BASE_URL , key)
```

This works well on my localhost but when I deploy the project on Vercel the app breaks and console.log(BASE_URL, key) gives me undefined undefined. any idea?
it's my first project on Vite and I have explored some similar questions but didn't resolve my problem

Comment: You have to manually set environment variables in the settings before building and deploying on Vercel.

Comment: @mocha , It doesn't work even after adding the environment variables in the vercel project settings

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to define them inside the `definedConfig` function in the **vite. config.ts** file
Something like

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    "process.env": process.env,
    ENV_KEY: process.env.ENV_KEY,
  },
});
```

And I can now use it

```
someObj: {
  key: import.meta.env.ENV_KEY,
},
```

I am not completely sure if it is necessary to define the `process.env` within the function

- https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/vite#environment-variables
- https://vitejs.dev/config/#using-environment-variables-in-config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks, was helpful! for anyone can check my project on github: https://github.com/prempro42/anonymous-chat-app

Answer (score -1):

To declare an Environment Variable for your Vercel deployment, go to the Environment Variables page of your Project Settings in the Vercel dashboard. From there you can enter the key/value pairs for your env variables and click 'Add' to add them to the project.

You can then access them as you are `import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY`

You can see how to set environment variables in the Vercel documentation at the following link: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

Comment: Please refrain from posting [link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). You can edit this post to adhere to the guidelines.

Comment: Sure thing. Updated.